# Why tick_sched_timer uses so much power on Linux

Tags: linux, powertop

According to my powertop (on 5.3.1 kernel):

```
Power est.              Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
 ...
  3.85 W      7,7 ms/s     437,0        Timer          tick_sched_timer
```

3.85W on a Laptop is huge, sometimes it gets even up to 6W.
I haven't seen this on earlier kernels (5.0.x), does anyone know how to reduce that power usage?

Comment: I've noticed this on my thinkpad x1 carbon running 5.4.8 as well.

Comment: I've noticed this on my XPS 15 9550 too.

Answer (score 3):

`tick_sched_timer` is part of the linux kernel's cpu scheduler. In this case, it is likely indicating many `context switches` and `cpu-wakeups` on your system.

If you are seeing it using a lot of power, it's likely that something on your system is causing a lot of `context switches` and/or `cpu-wakeups`. -- This could be related to a driver; such as a gpu driver, bluetooth, wifi, etc. - where it has some kind of aggressive update interval, or possibly a driver is firing many hardware interrupts... However, it could also be caused by some userpsace software, as well... even powertop will skew these numbers a bit.

You may have some success by disabling drivers (like bluetooth), when not in use (or if unused, completely blacklisting them). or changing cpu governors and/or using various power-saving methods/strategies... Depending on how your kernel is configured, reducing the timer tick may also save power. For example, some kernels may be build with `CONFIG_HZ_1000=y`, while others may be built with `CONFIG_HZ_250=y`. the latter should save some power.

Powertop may give you indications as to what the cause is; but `tick_sched_timer` isn't the root cause of your battery drain (it's only a symptom). It's likely some other thread, task or process; in the kernel or possibly in user-space.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but I dropped by usage from average above 2W to less than 1 by adjusting my settings with `tlpui`.

Go to Processor and tick the SCHED_POWERSAVE options to on.
You can also mess around with the many CPU adjustments in that category.

For Intel CPUs: go to Graphics and adjust the INTEL_GPU_FREQ to lower values, be sure to check what is available by using `sudo tlp-stat -g` beforehand.

For AMD CPUs: go to Graphics and set RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT and RADEON_DPM_STATE to low and battery, respectively.

Disabling bluetooth also seems to help.

Obviously this is not ideal as performance is lowered quite a bit, but if you value battery life more than performance then go with this.